# Explanation of try and catch

Tags: java

I thought that try and catch blocks stop at the statement the exception is caught, then it proceeds to the catch block. However, this is not the case and it's continuing to run the whole try block.

By the way, this is a tree with reference to 3 nodes: left, middle, and right.

The exception that is being caught is a `NullPointerException` where the animal name is being repeated twice. For example, 'Python' occurs at the left node, then 'Python' occurs again at the middle node.

Maybe it's because the exception is caught in another class? I'm not too sure.

So, the user input's 'AC' and the exception is caught at the `organismTree.addAnimalChild()`

```
else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("AC")) {
                try {
                    if(organismTree.getCursor().isPlant())
                        throw new Exceptions.IsPlantException();
                    if(organismTree.getCursor().isGetAllNodes())
                        throw new Exceptions.PositionNotAvailableException();
                    if(organismTree.getCursor().isHerbivore() && !organismTree.getCursor().isCarnivore())
                        throw new Exceptions.DietMismatchException();
                    System.out.print("What is the name of the organism?: ");
                    String addAnimalChild = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Is the organism a herbivore / a carnivore / an omnivore? (H / C / O) : ");
                    String addAnimalChildType = input.nextLine();
                    while (!addAnimalChildType.equalsIgnoreCase("H") && !addAnimalChildType.equalsIgnoreCase("C") && !addAnimalChildType.equalsIgnoreCase("O")) {
                        System.out.println("Please print out a correct letter");
                        addAnimalChildType = input.nextLine();
                    }
                        if (addAnimalChildType.equalsIgnoreCase("H")) {
                            organismTree.addAnimalChild(addAnimalChild, true, false);
                        } else if (addAnimalChildType.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
                            organismTree.addAnimalChild(addAnimalChild, false, true);
                        else
                            organismTree.addAnimalChild(addAnimalChild, true, true);
                    System.out.println("A(n) " + addAnimalChild + " has been successfully added as a prey for the " + organismTree.getCursor().getName());
                }
                catch(Exceptions.IsPlantException  | Exceptions.PositionNotAvailableException | Exceptions.DietMismatchException e)
                {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }
```

`addAnimalChild()` then redirects to another class.

`addAnimalChild method`

```
public void addAnimalChild(String name, boolean isHerbivore, boolean isCarnivore) throws
            IllegalArgumentException,  Exceptions.PositionNotAvailableException
    {
        try {
            cursor.addPrey(new OrganismNode(name, isHerbivore, isCarnivore));
        }
        catch(Exceptions.DietMismatchException | Exceptions.IsPlantException e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

then it redirects to addPrey() in another class.

`addPrey() Method`

```
 public void addPrey(OrganismNode preyNode) throws Exceptions.PositionNotAvailableException, Exceptions.IsPlantException, Exceptions.DietMismatchException
    {
            if (this.isGetAllNodes())
                throw new Exceptions.PositionNotAvailableException();
            if (this.isPlant()) {
                throw new Exceptions.IsPlantException();
            }
            if(((this.isHerbivore() && !this.isCarnivore()) && preyNode.isCarnivore()) || ((this.isCarnivore() && !this.isHerbivore()) && preyNode.isPlant()) )
                throw new Exceptions.DietMismatchException();
            if(this.getLeft() == null)
            {
                this.setLeft(preyNode);
                this.getLeft().setLeafNode(true);
                if(!preyNode.isCarnivore() && !preyNode.isHerbivore() && !preyNode.isOmnivore())
                    this.getLeft().setPlant(true);
                this.setLeafNode(false);
            }
            else if(this.getMiddle() == null)
            {
                try {
                    this.setMiddle(preyNode);
                    if (this.getMiddle().getName().equals(this.getLeft().getName())) {
                        this.setMiddle(null);
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    }
                    this.getMiddle().setLeafNode(true);
                    if (!preyNode.isCarnivore() && !preyNode.isHerbivore() && !preyNode.isOmnivore())
                        this.getMiddle().setPlant(true);
                    this.setLeafNode(false);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println("This prey already exists for this predator");
                }
            }
            else if(this.getRight() == null)
            {
                try {
                    this.setRight(preyNode);
                    if (this.getLeft().getName().equals(this.getRight().getName()) || this.getMiddle().getName().equals(this.getRight().getName())) {
                        this.setRight(null);
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    }
                    this.getRight().setLeafNode(true);
                    if (!preyNode.isCarnivore() && !preyNode.isHerbivore() && !preyNode.isOmnivore())
                        this.getRight().setPlant(true);
                    this.setLeafNode(false);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println("Animal already exists");
                }
            }
    }
```

It continues to print the System.out.println(), even though the exception was indeed caught.

I just thought of something, does the try block continue to run after it finishes the catch block?
It goes through the try block, catches the exception, goes through the catch block, then continues with where the try block left off at?

I can clarify more if you guys need me to.

Sorry if this is really long.

Comment: What System.out.println() are you talking about? You have several, including at least one inside of a catch block.

Comment: If an exception is being handled in an underlying method and not being thrown, then it will not escape out of the method it was handled in thus not reaching your top level try-catch

Comment: Your understanding seems over-complicated.  At some point an exception gets thrown - either by explicit ```throw``` statement or by implicit action such as trying to dereference a null reference.  At that point a search is made backwards through the stack looking for an exception handler for that specific exception class.  Execution resumes in that handler.

Comment: Note that this ```e.getMessage();``` in your exception handler does nothing useful. It gets the message text from an exception and then does nothing with that text.

Comment: You should post the stacktrace - it will help resolve the question

Answer (score 1):

None of your code is catching `NullPointerException`. You are only catching other Exception classes.